# can't use addChild method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dynatree

I'm using the dynatree plugin for the first time, and I'm trying to add nodes dynamically.
My code is below:

```
function DrawTree() {
 var names = GetChildName();  
 var rootNode = $("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree("getRoot");
 var childNode = rootNode.addChild({ title: names[0].Name });
}
```

On runtime an error displays

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Am I missing something ??
I have verify that i included needed libraries :

```
<script src="Jquery/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jquery/jquery/jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jquery/jquery/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Jquery/src/skin-vista/ui.dynatree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Jquery/src/jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the GetChildName(); returning an array and if so, does the objects inside that array have the .Name property?

Comment: yes GetChildName() return an array of objects that have Name as property

Comment: Can you tell if the exception is in your code (i.e. is rootNode null or something other than the dynatree command obejct) or somewhere inside the dynatree code? Can you step into this using the IE debugger (or a Firefox or Chrome debugger)?

Comment: rootNode is not null, the exception displays when trying to addChild. This method does not appear in the Intellicence also!!

Comment: i can't step into, while i'm trying the exception shows. it's like this method does not exist in the library

Comment: try adding dummy text for title to check, like :: rootNode.addChild({ title: 'Hello World' }); to see if that works...

Comment: You need to step into the getRoot call and you need to make sure you're getting back a DynaTreeNode object. That's the object that has `addChild`.

Comment: how do i know if i'm getting a DynaTreeNode?? $("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree("getRoot") suppose to return a DynaTreeNode right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be your problem, but it is worth a shot. Sometimes, when using jQuery with other libraries, you can run into conflicts with conflicting code. jQuery uses the $ sign as a shortcut for jQuery. The dynatree library also use the dollar sign for their functions.

I ran into this problem when implementing my tree and this is how I fixed it. As you can see, I replaced all '$' with 'jQuery'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

function DrawTree() {
    var names = GetChildName();
    jQuery("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree();

    var rootNode = jQuery("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree("getRoot");

    //Try adding a key
    var childNode = rootNode.addChild({ title: names[0].Name, key: "001" });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the tree first before you can call `dynatree("getRoot")`, e.g. in the simplest instance

```
function DrawTree() {
  var names = GetChildName();
  $("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree();
  var rootNode = $("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree("getRoot");
  var childNode = rootNode.addChild({ title: names[0].Name });
 }
```

should work. You can instead pass in lots of other options into the tree init step, e.g. see [the documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html).

Comment: OK, sorry. Can I check then that both `id="ProcessRoleTree"` actually exists on your page and that it exists in the DOM at the point you're calling this code, i.e. you're calling this from the jQuery ready handler rather than as the page loads? Otherwise I think you'll need to step into both of the `.dynatree` calls to make sure they're doing what you're expecting them to.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand what u mean!! i'm calling this method on button click

Comment: $("#ProcessRoleTree").dynatree("getRoot") suppose to return a DynaTreeNode right? in my case i guess it does not return DynaTreeNode Object any idea why??

Comment: No, sorry. Here's an example on jsFiddle using your code that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rupw/RL5Gd/

Comment: ok thank you. still not working here!!! .dynatree("getRoot") is not returning DynaTreeNode Object... i tried it from onCreate and it worked!! weird!!